# localStorage AngularJS does not save anything

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

I want to create a text area where if i add some text and click on save, the text should be saved in localStorage. So if i open the text area again, i can see it still there.

**HTML**

```
    <ion-view view-title="CWIN 2016 - Votre avis">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card user-infos-card">
      <div class="item aw-dark-blue"> <h2 class="activity-name"></h2> Notes</div>
       <textarea ng-model="note" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
       <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left aw-dark-blue" ng-click="saveNote()" ng-model="note">Enregistrer vos notes</div>
        <div ng-show="error">
          <p class="form-error-message">Veuillez saisir des notes</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**JS**

```
   angular.module('companion.noteBookController', ['LocalStorageModule'])

.controller('noteBookController', function ($scope, localStorageService){

    $scope.note=localStorageService.get('note');

    $scope.saveNote=function() {
        localStorageService.set('note', $scope.note);
    }

});
```

[image]

I don't underdstand the problem. Besides I don't have any errors.

Comment: console.log(localStorageService.isSupported)) // is it giving true?

Comment: Can you please check if the note is being actually saved into localStorage? In chrome, go to developer tools > application > localStorate. You should see your key named 'note' and a value. I have the feeling that the problem is actually with your HTML5 markup.

Comment: you can use $localStorage... `$localStorage.something = something;`

Comment: Use of $localStorage will help.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left aw-dark-blue" ng-click="saveNote(note)">Enregistrer vos notes</div>
```

and in js

```
angular.module('companion.noteBookController', ['$localStorage'])

.controller('noteBookController', function ($scope, $localStorage){


    $scope.saveNote=function(note_val) {
        console.log(note_val);
        $localStorage.note = note_val;
    }

});
```

if you want to get value then you can use this

```
var my_note =  $localStorage.note;
```